# Is there a way to make nginx start a uwsgi process at the first request?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I was thinking if is there a way to make nginx start a uwsgi proccess at the first request, so I can save a lot of memory with idle sites.

Someone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nginx don't start uwsgi processes at all. It's uWSGI server job.

Probably, you're looking for "cheap" mode:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc#cheap

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, to use cheap mode you need at least 1 uwsgi proccess per site. My point is to use nginx to start the backend if it's dead, so at the first request you can start the backend, it it's idle you can stop it and save a lot of memory

Answer (score 1):

Nginx (by design) cannot generate new processes (this is why you do not have cgi support in nginx).
You can use the cheap+idle modes of uwsgi, to start with only the master and rip-off workers after a specified time (set by --idle) of inactivity.

If even starting only the master is too much for you (i suppose you want the minimal memory usage) you can look at the old-school inetd/xinetd or newer upstart socket bridge and systemd socket activation to activate uWSGI only on specific connections